# AWS CodeBuild: Skipping invalid file path, UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have the following buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - npm install -g aws-cdk@1.72.0
  build:
    commands:
      - cd Lambda
      - cd NetworkRailGateway-Functions
      - for d in ./*/; do (npm install --only=prod); done
      - cd .. 
      - cd RealtimeStations-Functions
      - for d in ./*/; do (npm install --only=prod); done
      - cd .. 
      - cdk synth > cfStack.yml
      - ls
      - pwd
artifacts:
  files:
    - cfStack.yml
```

The ls command is showing the cfStack.yml file is present in the current directory, however, I do get the following artifact error which seems to imply that the file does not exist

```
[Container] 2021/05/20 14:10:51 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/05/20 14:10:51 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/05/20 14:10:51 Expanding base directory path: .
[Container] 2021/05/20 14:10:51 Assembling file list
[Container] 2021/05/20 14:10:51 Expanding .
[Container] 2021/05/20 14:10:51 Expanding file paths for base directory .
[Container] 2021/05/20 14:10:51 Assembling file list
[Container] 2021/05/20 14:10:51 Expanding cfStack.yml
[Container] 2021/05/20 14:10:51 Skipping invalid file path cfStack.yml
[Container] 2021/05/20 14:10:51 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/05/20 14:10:51 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching artifact paths found
```

I have also tried ./cfStack.yml to no avail.

Comment: What is the output of ls?

Comment: ```[Container] 2021/05/20 14:10:51 Running command ls
NetworkRailGateway-Functions
README.md
RealtimeStations-Functions
cdk.context.json
cdk.json
cdk.out
cfStack.yml
src```

Answer (score 1):

It looks the file is present inside the directory 'Lambda'. So you should prefix the direcotry name as below.

artifacts:
files:
- 'Lambda/cfStack.yml'

Or you should set the base directory as below.

artifacts:
files:
- 'cfStack.yml'
base-directory: 'Lambda'

Comment: The file is in the current directory and shows up in ls output.